# Nativescript Vue.js location GPS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I recently developed an Android App with native vue.js.

I used geolocation plugin and its works perfectly on devices with google play services but not on those where Google services are deactivated.

I am searching for a module which can make location possible on devices without Google services.

Your help is needed.

Comment: this post may be helpful https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/access-to-locationmanager-in-android/5413

Answer (score 0):

As it is an android app, you can use LocationManager and set the  appropriate provider, GPS or NETWORK.
I am not an expert in vue, so can not give you code but as you have access to all native APIs in nativescript, you can convert that.
Sample

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

I have used it before in nativescript angular app.

For location strategies, you can refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies).

Comment: The geo location plugin used to handle everything with `LocationManager` only until Google started recommending Play Services which is powerful and efficient as mentioned in the given link.

Comment: True but problem is there when Google services are deactivated or not updated

Comment: Agreed, but you can check and request for an update in that case.

Comment: Yes, could not agree more, this should be the way forward. Update the services if not available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import * as application from "application";

const PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9999;

...
isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        const googleApiAvailability = com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        const resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(application.android.context);
        if (resultCode != com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(application.android.context, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
 ...
```

It would notify and install play services if not available.

Comment: Thank you Manoj. The problem is that the device has been rooted and the new customized android into it does not support Google services. I need a location plugin which does not require google services

Comment: In that case you may try the older version of plugin, may be `v3.0.1` that would use `LocationManager` for fetching location. But I'm unsure whether it will be compatible with latest version of NativeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and finally I fixed it, the problem is, nativescript-geolocation v3.0.1 do not deponds on google play service, but it is outdated and not work with tns v6. this is my solution:

you can get the code of nativescript-geolocation v3.0.1, modify a little, and then, depend the source code on your tns v6 project, it works. following is the details.

```
git@github.com:NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation.git
cd nativescript-geolocation
git checkout -b your-branch v3.0.1
```

next, modify the code of src/geolocation.android.ts file, just one line

```
-    let currentContext = <android.app.Activity>androidAppInstance.currentContext;
+    let currentContext = <android.app.Activity>androidAppInstance.context;
```

next, use the source code dependency in your project,

```
tns plugin add /path/to/nativescript-geolocation/src
```

you can see `demo/app/main-page.ts` file in the git repo for how to use this plugin of this version.